# Configuration Error

Tags: asp.net

I have created a basic ASP.NET membership application, whereby users can login to view certain pages or create a new account. The problem is whenever I upload this to the server I am getting a configuration error (see below) Any ideas as to how I could fix this would be greatly appreciated.

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during
>   the processing of a configuration file
>   required to service this request.
>   Please review the specific error
>   details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The '='
>   character, hexadecimal value 0x3D,
>   cannot be included in a name. Line 25,
>   position 10.
>
> Source Error:

```
 Line 23:             Set explicit="true" to force declaration of all variables.
Line 24:         -->
Line 25:        <addkey=”ConnectionString” value="server=mysqlhost\sqlexpress;uid=u70771928;pwd=6f4c4e;database=d60702836"  />
Line 26:         <customErrors mode="Off"/>
Line 27:        <roleManager enabled="true" />
```

> Source File:
>   \smb1\mnt\w0341\d49\s39\b021bcd6\www\web.config
>   Line: 25
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:2.0.50727.3603;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082

Comment: could you post the relevant lines of your config file?

Comment: Show us some code. Paste the content of your web,config here.

Comment: You should provide the web.config content (only the membership block, if it is around the line 25) and edit your question to set the error message as a quote

Comment: @All, the relevant part of the web.config file was there, it was being hidden by the OP not marking it as a code block

Comment: Also, you may want to change your password :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `"` instead of `”` in `<addkey=”ConnectionString”`

Comment: You need a space in the addkey.

Answer (score 2):

This is, from the looks of it, because you've mis-typed "add key" as "addkey" at the beginning of the line.

```
<addkey=”ConnectionString” value="server=mysqlhost\sqlexpress;uid=u70771928;pwd=6f4c4e;database=d60702836"  />
```

Should be:

```
<add key=”ConnectionString” value="server=mysqlhost\sqlexpress;uid=u70771928;pwd=6f4c4e;database=d60702836"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful of your quotes (").
In your question they seem to be different from the standard one (” instead of ")

Comment: But the real problem here is probably the missing space :)

Comment: yeup, that it is, although I do wonder how asp.net will respond to the curly quotes, so well worth you mentioning =)

Answer (score 0):

There is no space between `<addkey`.  It should be `<add key`.